# Making a number increment when a class is clicked

Tags: javascript

So right now I have this code:

```
 var s = 0;

 $('.inner').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    $(this).removeClass("inner");
    s++;
    $('#sslots').replaceWith(s);
 };
```

But for some reason, the javascript wont update, it will start out as blank (not zero) and then change to 1 once I click one of the div's with "inner" as the class but then won't do anything after that..

Comment: Use `$(document).on('click', '.inner', function() { ...` instead of `$('.inner').click(function () {`

Comment: @Tushar: Why do you think that would fix the issue?

Comment: @FelixKling just a good habit to write delegated event

Comment: @TributetoAPJKalamSir: But irrelevant (and actually misleading!) to the problem. Not everything has to be delegated.

Comment: @FelixKling Because, the HTML is not included in question, I thought, the issue is with event binding. Also, the last comment in question also says this

Comment: @Tushar OP said the first one is working.. so the chances are less for that

Comment: @Tushar: Well, it looked like you suggested to use event delegation because the OP removes the class `.inner` (which would be wrong and misleading).

Comment: @ArunPJohny And OP is also removing the class, on which event is binded

Comment: @Tushar: Removing the class does not magically remove the event handler, if that's what you are implying.

Comment: @FelixKling may be that is why he advised to use event delegation... but if the elements are not dynamic then `one()` could be a better choice(IMHO)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is after your first click the element `sslots` does not exists because you are replacing it with the number, instead you have to change the content of `sslots` - you can use `.text()` for that

```js
var s = 0;

$('.inner').one('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass("selected");
  $(this).removeClass("inner");
  s++;
  $('#sslots').text(s);
});
```

```css
.inner {
  color: green;
}
.selected {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sslots">0</div>
<div class="inner">inner</div>
<div class="inner">inner</div>
<div class="inner">inner</div>
<div class="inner">inner</div>
<div class="inner">inner</div>
```

Also from the code it looks like you want to execute the click once per `inner` element(ie if you click multiple times in an element only first one should count), in that cause use .one() to register a handler which will be executed only once

Comment: What would a function look like that made ALL the classes go back to inner and the variable s = 0?

Comment: @Jop http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/t5pvsqsq/2/ - in that case I would recommend using event delegation